# Page reloading not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, refresh, reload

I'm working on an internet game which is comunicating with another server via websocket and I have a problem with reloading the page.

```
if(objekt.score > numGoal && objekt.score < numGoal+800 && numGoal == 10000 && lightsAv)
    {   
        if(!winLOpen)
        {
            winLOpen = true;
            doit(objekt);
            myLWindow = window.open("page address", "name", "directories=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=auto,height=auto");
            setTimeout(function()
            { 
                myLWindow.close(); 
                document.location.href = 'http://10.1.1.19:1880/simple2'
            }, 30000);
        }
    }

    else if(objekt.score > numGoal && numGoal == 10000 && !lightsAv)
    {   

        document.location.href = 'http://10.1.1.19:1880/simple2';
    }
```

In "if" branch reloading via href is working great, but in "else if" branch it's not working. And I am sure that this branch is reached, because I tried console.log in there and it worked just fine. I tried almost every command which I could find on the internet including window.location.reload() and so on.
Can anybody help please?

Comment: We have no way to evaluate what those variable values in the `else` are. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: Values are not important, because I already tried console.log in every branch so else if branch was reached, but document.location.href command didn't work.

Comment: No reason it wouldn't work if it is reached. Probably not being reached ... in other words the conditional is not truthy